# Sound not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I have a problem with my sound which I suspect has something to do with the fact that I have hooked up a HDMI monitor. I've followed several guides but nothing has helped yet.

My laptop stopped producing any sound from one day to another. In settings, there is only one sound output device registered: 'Speakers - Built-in Audio'. When I open pavucontrol I can see the bar moving, indicating that I should be hearing something from playing a youtube video.

I am using the following soundcard:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company CM238 HD Audio Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 140
Memory at b4528000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at b4510000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

I have tried force-reloading alsamixer and checked all settings in pavucontrol. Also followed every step in this guide: [I cannot hear any sounds on the computer](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-nosound.html.en)

There are a lot of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices showing. I have connected a HDMI monitor, which does not have built in speakers, and suspect this is where the issues started. Here is the response of 'aplay -l'

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC295 Analog [ALC295 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I have a dual boot with Windows 10, on which the sound works fine. So that eliminates a hardware issue. Does anyone have an idea of where to look next?

--- Update

To add to the mystery, when I took the laptop out of sleep mode (not a full reboot), the sound worked again. I'm afraid it will happen again, but I've spotted some minor differences in the previous results. I'm not sure what's caused the sound outage..

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company CM238 HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 133
    Memory at b4528000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b4510000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Specifically, the IRQ flag changed.

Comment: It mighr be helpful to know if IRQ 140 is always broken and all others work.

Comment: Rebooted my machine and the sound still works but the audio controller uses IRQ 140 again

Comment: The other thing to consider is if you use Windows first and then reboot or if you power on and go straight to Ubuntu. It can effect some cards. Note Power On <> Reboot.

Comment: This seems to be it! I pressed restart on windows and then booted into Ubuntu and now the sound is gone again. Any clues on how to prevent it or solve it when it happens?